# How to remove presentity users entry in kamailio server?

Tags: sip, kamailio, user-presence

I found that in:

```
kamctl db show presentity
```

Is the presence information of the users, but how can I errase such entry? of a user?

And how can I define only one entry in that database by user?
I use this code, when I receive a publish but this adds a new entry every time.

```
if(is_method("PUBLISH"))
    {
        if($hdr(Sender)!= NULL)
            handle_publish("$hdr(Sender)");
        else
            handle_publish();
        t_release();
    }
```

The idea is have the possibility of a user publish multiple times, but have just one entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this: https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/modules/presence.html#presence.p.xavp_cfg

To order by `timestamp` you just need this line `modparam("presence", "xavp_cfg", "pres")`.

This way, I think that your problem is solved.

Let me know if it's result.